# Is it possible to modify components stored in an AbstractCollection in Netbeans Swing Gui Builder (Matisse)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, matisse

I have some swing components (JSliders and JTextFields to be precise) in an AbstractCollection. The user will decide in runtime how many components are needed each time. Is there any way to do that through a GUI editor, preferably the Swing GUI Builder in NetBeans or any other IDE, in order to use the facilities a GUI Editor provides?

One work around I have thought so far is to put all the components in a JTable and each time I will create a JTable of an appropriate size. I wonder though if there is any other way.

Comment: Do you mean you want all old components removed, then a new set of components are added?

Comment: Yes, if the user wants to change the number of the jComponents, the old components will have to be removed and replaced by the new ones. But the number of them will be determined each time in runtime (that is why I have them in an abstract collection).